# Correct way to extract uid from current_user.get_id() from flask_ldap3_login?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I finally got flask-login + flask-ldap3-login working together, and when I call current_user.get_id() I get a string like "uid=myuid,ou=people,ou=group,ou=internal,o=org"

I know I can split up this string and carve out the piece I want, but as these are attributes it feels like I should be able to get current_user.get_id().uid or something like that, to get only and exact the piece I want.

Is there anything of the sort, or any extra safe way to carve it up other than just cutting out the piece between 'uid=' and ','?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ldap_app.User.get_id` [returns a unicode value](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/blob/master/ldap_app.py#L48):

```
# Declare an Object Model for the user, and make it comply with the
# flask-login UserMixin mixin.
class User(UserMixin):
    def __init__(self, dn, username, data):
        self.dn = dn
        self.username = username
        self.data = data

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.dn

    def get_id(self):
        return self.dn
```

Based on the [comments](https://github.com/nickw444/flask-ldap3-login/blob/master/flask_ldap3_login/__init__.py#L221) in `LDAP3LoginManager.save_user`, `User.data` should be getting a dict of userdata:

```
def save_user(self, callback):
        '''
        This sets the callback for saving a user that has been looked up from
        from ldap.
        The function you set should take a user dn (unicode), username
        (unicode) and userdata (dict), and memberships (list).
        ::
            @ldap3_manager.save_user
            def save_user(dn, username, userdata, memberships):
                return User(username=username, data=userdata)
        Your callback function MUST return the user object in your ORM
        (or similar). as this is used within the LoginForm and placed
        at ``form.user``
        Args:
            callback (function): The function to be used as the save user
                                 callback.
        '''

        self._save_user = callback
        return callback
```

So `current_user.data`, rather than `current_user.get_id()`, should have a dict of information.

If that dict doesn't have what you need, you'll likely be stuck just [pulling apart the `dn` string](https://www.fir3net.com/Programming/Python/python-split-a-string-into-a-dictionary.html):

```
useful_data = dict(x.split('=') for x in current_user.get_id().split(','))
```

Comment: Wow, yes, User.data has more data than I know what to do with, thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad it helped. One of the reasons I like working with Python is that, even when a library is un- or under-documented, the source code tends to be pretty legible.